# How was multiplayer implemented on a single core processor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-input, multiplayer

How was implemented multiplayer on a single core in game consoles like Sega Genesis. How it was possible to process two gamepads and therefore two game windows in parallel in one thread. I'm asking because I myself am writing a game and want to understand how to implement the processing of user input from scratch without using multi-threading and without interrupting the program, as it was done before. If you want to mark my question as duplicate, see if that question answers exactly my question, because I didn't find the answer, no matter how I searched. Thanks.

Comment: It was possible to "process two gamepads and therefore two game windows in parallel" exactly the same way that a computer can process a keyboard with fifty, or so, keys, any one of which can be pressed at any time.

Comment: It's a strange question to ask. You just google how to implement input processing, do it, and see if it required any threads or not. Most probably you'll observe that no threads were needed. Unless you're making your own OS, you don't need to *know* how it works under the hood.

Comment: Threading wasn't really a thing on the Gensis/Megadrive they were running on raw hardware so gamepad might come in as an interrupt which is the equivalent of getting preempted updating some state and then returning to normal render loop. [Or it could have just been on a timer](https://blog.bigevilcorporation.co.uk/2012/04/30/sega-megadrive-7-gamepad-input-and-the-game-loop/)

Comment: "How was implemented multiplayer on a single core" - Ever heard of "state machines"? You keep track of the current state of the `n` things you care about, then you update that state for one at a time. Do it fast enough and switch between things you update fast enough and it seems to the user like things are happening in parall, even if everything is sequential. No magic; just fast computers and clever programming.

Comment: Hint: Learn about game loops, otherwise known as "event loops", part of a pattern called [Event Driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). There are [huge books](https://www.gameenginebook.com) on the subject.

Comment: Consider how much programming was done prior to the advent of threads. These really only came to the forefront in the late 1990s.